# compact list object in a tidy dataframe R

Tags: r, list, compact-database

I have a list object (results) and am trying to compact it in a tidy data frame. But I am not sure how to achieve that.

[[varying from 1to 3nsim][[varying from 1 to 9]][[varying from 1to 3]][[varying from 1to 3]]

I have such nested list and I want to compact it into a tidy data frame of dimension nrow =nsimx9x3x3 et ncol = 26 .
any idea how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share in your question a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) to showcase your data and expected output? It's really hard to imagine what you want to achieve. Also it seems that you are describing a four dimensional structure, which doesn't sound like a data frame at all

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `nsimx9x3x3` rows (but I have no clue how you get `26` columns), maybe this could work for you

```
as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(lst)))
```

where `lst` is your nested list

Comment: Sorry, It seems I was not very clear in the post. from the nested lists. I want to have a dataframe with nsimx9x3x3 and 26 columns (outputs of the analysis function)

Comment: @Ibrahima Could you provide a small example of the nested list as well as the expected output. I have no picture in my mind what you are looking for

Comment: [[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
  i rho_theorique    rho_xy rho_xz     rho_yz rho_xy_cca rho_xz_cca rho_yz_cca prop_miss method mech SimType  estimate std.error statistic       df   p.value
x 2          0.25 0.1982005    0.5 0.05232742  0.2159688        0.5 0.06095765      0.05   norm MCAR  MyTest 0.2213937 0.1147183   1.92989 48.04456 0.0595361
        X2.5..   X97.5..       riv    lambda       fmi       ubar           b          t dfcom
x -0.009257401 0.4520447 0.1530611 0.1327432 0.1667236 0.01141335 0.001310204 0.01316029    98